# Kotlin's Dukat is generating code with a tons of error

Tags: kotlin-js

Here's my current `gradle.build.kts`

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("js") version "1.5.31"
}

group = "me.fan87"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-nodejs:0.0.7")
    implementation(npm("ascii-art", "2.8.5"))
    runtimeOnly(npm("electron", "18.0.2", true))
    implementation(npm("electron", "18.0.2"))
}
```

(electron is duplicated because I tried using `implementation(npm("electron", "18.0.2", true))` before and doesn't work, I'm just testing out if it works and that's not happening)

I know that dukat is still in beta/alpha, but isn't there really a way to do this?
I'm using kotlin because I want code completion, so using dynamic is not happening.
Just wondering if there's any alternative option, if not then RIP I guess (It took me 5 hours on googling it, trying different things already : (  )

Here's a screenshot (I can't send it now cuz I'm a new user so I'll provide an URL)
[Screenshot](https://gato.host/Aw1RNGCkh)

Edit:
The worst part is everything is broken, literally everything.
I realized that `-Xerror-tolerance-policy` was a thing, and guess what? It isn't working either lmao  [YouTrack](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-42426), and [What it supposed to be](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/js-ir-compiler.html#preview-generation-of-typescript-declaration-files-d-ts)